# how to use sass using in vuejs3/vite

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I starting with vite / vuejs 3

after installing sass with npm install -D sass I tried to add my _variables.js file this to vite.config.js

```
css: {preprocessorOptions: {scss: {additionalData: `@import" ./src/css/_variables.scss ";`,},},},
```

din't work!

it also worked in vue.config

```
css: {
     loaderOptions: {
       sass: {
         sassOptions: {
            prependData: `@import" @ / css / _variables.scss ";`,
         }
       }
     }
   },
```

after this tried to import the file in main.js import "./css/_variables.scss"

Unfortunately, my components cannot find the variables, where is the error

Answer (score 30, accepted):

here is my working setup, got it from the [vite docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#css-pre-processors) and with the command `yarn add -D sass`

```json
// package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
   ...
    "vue": "^3.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "sass": "^1.32.11",
    "vite": "^2.2.3"
  }
}
```

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()]
})
```

```html
// App.vue
<template>...</template>
<script>...</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import "./assets/style.scss";
</style>
```

```css
// style.scss
[data-theme="dark"] {
  --bg-color1: #121416;
  --font-color: #f4f4f4;
}
[data-theme="light"] {
  --bg-color1: #f4f4f4;
  --font-color: #121416;
}
...
body {
  background-color: var(--bg-color1);
  color: var(--font-color);
}
```

and my `vue.config.js` is clean - nothing fancy there.

Comment: Have you managed to compile any nested SCSS imports? I'm struggling to figure this out myself. Trying to get material components web to work. Seems like there is an issue with the @forward syntax. https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/4140

Comment: Have you tried to import your scss files in `main.js`? For me it works to import multiple scss files via `./` there.

Comment: Thanks. I was originally doing that myself too. Seems to be a bug with material design.

Answer (score 50):

Vite is a litte bit different

```js
    import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
    
    export default defineConfig({
      css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
          scss: {
            additionalData: `
              @import "./src/styles/_animations.scss";
              @import "./src/styles/_variables.scss";
              @import "./src/styles/_mixins.scss";
              @import "./src/styles/_helpers.scss";
            `
          }
        }
      }
    })
```

Comment: This is the correct answer if you are importing for use in all components, avoiding repeat imports.

Comment: This works brilliantly. Just remember to use `@use` instead of `@import` if it complains about `@forward` rules needing to be written before other rules.

Answer (score 15):

For Vue3, as stated in the documentation: https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#css-pre-processors

You only need to add

```
npm add -D sass
```

And in the script tag use

```
<style lang="scss">
// OR
<style lang="sass">
```

Comment: Remember to run command "npm run dev" again for it to take effect.

Answer (score 6):

My problem was the following: I coudn't get scss variables within `<style lang="scss">` and now this is my good config:

```js
// vite.config.ts

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    ...
  ],
  ...,
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: ` // just variables loaded globally
          @import "./src/assets/styles/setup/fonts";
          @import "./src/assets/styles/setup/colors";
          @import "./src/assets/styles/setup/mixins";
        `
      }
    }
  }
});

// App.vue

<style lang="scss"> // the main file that imports everything related with styles
@import "@/assets/styles/main.scss";
</style>
```

Comment: What got it working for me was really the `<style lang="scss"> // the main file that imports everything related with styles
@import "@/assets/styles/main.scss";
</style> ` with my specific location for the scss in the App.Vue

Comment: Great, this Vite configuration and the importing in App.vue with lang=sass worked for me. Thanks. I was also able to import within the <script setup>, maybe because I have just 'sass' installed too.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and simply solved it by installing sass as a Dev dependency.

```
npm i -D sass
```

Answer (score 3):

Solutions:

1. "**npm add -D sass**" ----------  (**-g flag** will not work in vite now 16/02/2022).
   Or,
2. "**yarn add -D sass**" - Run these comments in your command line.
3. In main.js file "**import './style.scss**' " will not work, so I added my sass file in html

Comment: What syntax did you use to add from your index.html?

Answer (score 1):

If already install sass in your react.js app. Uninstall it.
Once Uninstall is done Check your packge.json file. It's will look like that.

> ```
> "devDependencies": {
> "@types/react": "^18.0.17",
> "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
> "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.1.0",
> "vite": "^3.1.0"   }
> ```

Then Ren this command

```
npm cache clean --force or npm cache clean -f
```

Close your Vscode and Re-open it.
Now Reinstall **sass** in your react vite app.

```
# .scss and .sass
npm add -D sass

# .less
npm add -D less

# .styl and .stylus
npm add -D stylus
```

Once Installation done your json file look like that.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "vite": "^3.1.0"
  }
```

Comment: This is not question related to React.js but Vue but overall it similar fix path